# newenvironment and restatable

Tags: environments

I'm trying to create a new enviroment using restatable, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools,thm-restate}

\newenvironment{restat}{\begin{restatable}{theorem}{A}}{\end{restatable}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{restat}A\end{restat}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Runaway argument?

! File ended while scanning use of \thmt@collect@body.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> pr
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome! It is not a regular environment. It is collecting the entire body of the environment and then processing it. It is probably doing this by collecting everything up until `\end{restatable}`. But it never finds this because it is not there to be found. That is, it needs this to literally come somewhere in the source after `\begin{restatable}`. This is making some assumptions as I've not really looked carefully through the code, but I think they are fairly safe assumptions. It seems to work like e.g. `environ`.

Comment: You can probably nest them if you are careful, though. I've done that with `environ` environments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `restatable` environment needs to see an explicit `\end{restatable}` since it's actually collecting the entire environment body. As such, you need to capture the contents yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,environ}
\usepackage{thmtools,thm-restate}

\NewEnviron{restat}{%
  \begin{restatable}{theorem}{A}
  \BODY
  \end{restatable}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{restat}
something
\end{restat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is actually what I've used before. This time, I did it differently because of the comments in the manual about `amsmath`. Do you know when the alternative version given there is actually preferable, by any chance? I'm not clear whether it matters in this case or not.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to use `\restatable` and `\endrestatable` as it's often the case with environments that need to grab their contents.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools,thm-restate}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newenvironment{restat}
 {\restatable{theorem}{important}}
 {\endrestatable}

\begin{document}

\begin{restat}
A restatable theorem
\end{restat}

Let's restate it

\important*

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `restatable` is not a regular environment. Rather, it scans forward to collect the entire body of the environment and then processes it. The code for `\end{restatable}` is, in fact, empty.

This depends on it *literally* finding `\end{restatable}` in the input stream. But since that is not in your document's source (after `\begin{restatable}`, it never finishes looking for it. It reaches `\end{document}` or whatever first.

To create a wrapper around an environment of this kind, you need to collect the body of your environment in the same way and then feed it to the wrapped environment. `environ` enables you to do this conveniently.

Here's a solution using the example from page 3 of `environ`'s manual. I did it this way because it suggests this may be especially suitable if using `amsmath` although I'm not altogether sure whether it matters in this case.

It helps to avoid, I think, the possibility of conflicts with `\BODY`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{thmtools,thm-restate}
\makeatletter
% mnodified from page 3 of environ manual
\newcommand\wrap[1]{\begin{restatable}{theorem}{A}#1\end{restatable}}
\newenvironment{restat}{\Collect@Body\wrap}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
 \begin{restat}A\end{restat}
\end{document}
```